# Easier way of getting 1 cell from a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Right now I'm adding data to a dataset and then selecting the first row and column in the first table of that data. There must be some shorter way of doing this?

```
SqlCommand LoadCmd = new SqlCommand("Select start_tid from EKGDATA where ekgmaaleid = @ekgmaaleid", GlobalVariables.offCon);
LoadCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ekgmaaleid", maaleid);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(LoadCmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds);

string dato = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in
>   the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are
>   ignored.

```
using(SqlCommand LoadCmd = new SqlCommand("Select start_tid from EKGDATA where ekgmaaleid = @ekgmaaleid", GlobalVariables.offCon))
{
   LoadCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ekgmaaleid", maaleid);
   GlobalVariables.offCon.Open();
   var result = LoadCmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

`ExecuteScalar` returns `object` type data, You can cast/convert it to your required type.

*(Consider using [`using statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with your `SqlCommand` object)*

Answer (score 2):

```
string dato;
using (var offCon = new SqlConnection("..."))
using (var LoadCmd = new SqlCommand("Select start_tid from EKGDATA where ekgmaaleid = @ekgmaaleid", GlobalVariables.offCon))
{
    LoadCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ekgmaaleid", maaleid);
    offCon.Open();
    dato = (string)LoadCmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: (string) is instead of Convert.ToString? Clever.

Answer (score 1):

If your query returns just one row with only one column then the right method is [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
SqlCommand LoadCmd = new SqlCommand("Select start_tid from EKGDATA where ekgmaaleid = @ekgmaaleid", GlobalVariables.offCon);
LoadCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ekgmaaleid", maaleid);
object result = LoadCmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Then, depending on the datatype expected, you check for null return and try to convert the result.
So, assuming that the value returned is a string

```
if(result != null)
{
    string dato = result.ToString();
}
```

The checking for null is mandatory in your case unless you are absolutely certain that the row identified by the WHERE clause always exists in your datatable. 
Also keep note that **ExecuteScalar** returns NULL and not `DBNull.Value` if the value required is not found

Comment: You should not be concerned for null in the start_tid column, but if your parameter `@ekgmaaleid` is always matched against `ekgmaaleid` column. If the where clause doesn't find any record matching the parameter value then the result of ExecuteScalar will be null.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Well that won't happen either, but I'll look back on your code next time I make a program with an SQL connection.